# OkHttp Upload File - Error File Not Found - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I am kind of new to Kotlin and OkHttp. I am trying to select an image from the gallery and upload it via OkHttp. I get an error "File not found". I believe that the problem is with the `mSelectedImageFileUri`. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have the following code:

Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Activity

```
companion object {
        private const val READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1
        private const val PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 2
        private val MEDIA_TYPE_JPG = "image/jpg".toMediaType()
}

 private fun showImageChooser(){
        var galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && data!!.data != null){
                mSelectedImageFileUri = data.data
     }
}



private val client = OkHttpClient()

fun uploadFile (){

        val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("Title","Name")
                .addFormDataPart("Image","Image.jpg",File("${mSelectedImageFileUri}").asRequestBody(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG))
                .build()
        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("custom url")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build()
        
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("ERROR"+e)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response?.body?.string()
               
                runOnUiThread {
                    //do something
                }

            }
        })

}
```

Comment: `File("${mSelectedImageFileUri}"` You cannot use the File class for an uri as your uri is a content scheme and no file system path. Use the uri directly with opning an InputStream and using InputSTreamRequestBody instead.

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196